# Python --- find current or last logged on user

Tags: python, wmi

I am trying to find current or last logged on user

Part of the script

```
# userIP has been defined
# try to access wmi

try:
    c = wmi.WMI(userIP)
except: 
    print "Cannot access WMI for", userIP
    sys.exit()


for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print os.Caption

for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    print us.LogonId
```

I get the following output

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
999
997
996
4831418
8883496
8883473
8883457
8883437
671914
```

Do these numbers represent recently and currently logged on users? How to convert them to DOMAIN\username format? And if they can be converted, how to get latest user?

EDIT

I tried

```
for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
        print(user.Antecedent)
```

But I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\lookup.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(user.Antecedent)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 555, in __getattr__
    return WMI (moniker=value)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1290, in connect
    handle_com_error ()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217406, 'OLE error 0x80041002', No
ne, None)>
```

Then I tried

```
for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
        print(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
```

But I get the error

```
  File ".\lookup.py", line 48
    print(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I troubleshoot these?

Comment: This might help... http://serverfault.com/q/32633/193130. It's for the command line `wmic` instead of the python API, but you should be able to call the same API from python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to dig down a bit to get the added info. Unfortunately, I can't recall my source for this:

```
for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
        print(user.Antecedent)
```

You can get the properties printed from that as well, for example replace the final line with:

```
print(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
```

I get:

```
MyPC\nerdwaller
```

**edit**

I should have mentioned two things:

1. I am using Python3, so for you to use print as a function in python 2.x:

   `from __future__ import print_function`
2. There are issues iterating through that, as you are seeing.  There are various solutions, and since I don't know your use-case... not the cleanest solution, you can wrap that in a try/catch:

```
for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    try:
        for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
            print(user.Antecedent)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Please see EDIT in the original question

Comment: I made the changes, I am still getting errors. How to troubleshoot these errors. I listed them under EDIT2 in original question.

Comment: @Glowie - In your script, you omitted part 2 of my edit, as you can see from your edit1 - it is the same error as before (the first error under edit 1).

Comment: I just realized I didn't include the second edit, I will add EDIT 3. There are no errors but I am trying to format the output ...

Comment: @Glowie - That is up for you to do, generally speaking you should not keep expanding the scope of your question.  It makes those that answer keep coming back and it expands the scope of the question making it harder to reference for future people with a similar initial question.  tldr; If you are having unrelated issues to your initial question, you need to make a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer returns many users, including yourself and possibly the person logged in.

I find that a more reliable way of discovering the person logged on is to get the owner of the `explorer.exe` process.

Try the following to **get a nice tuple containing the domain and username of the currently logged on user of the remote Windows computer:**

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI('target_hostname')
for process in c.Win32_Process(name='explorer.exe'):
    print process.GetOwner()
```

If no one is logged in and you want the last person who was, you can try the following to **get the SID of the most recently logged in user of the remote Windows computer:**

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI('target_hostname')
profiles = []
for up in c.Win32_UserProfile():
    profiles.append((up.LastUseTime, up.SID, up.LocalPath))
profiles.sort(reverse=True)
for p in profiles:
    print p
```

The first element of the `profiles` list will contain the most recently logged in user. Unfortunately this is just the SID. The `LocalPath` part can at least tell you their username if you look at their home directory name (not always reliable). I'm not sure how to convert a SID into a username in Python.

Comment: Thank you for contributing this. The accepted answer here did not work reliably for us, but this did the trick.