# Compare two text file with logs of logon/logout user

Tags: python

I have two text file with logs - when user logon on PC and logout on PC
example logon logs:

```
name logon on NAMEOFPC in time date ip 
kate logon on DESKTOP in 8:38:24,10 23.06.2023 IP:192.168.x.x
jake logon on DESKTOP123 in 11:15:10,10 23.06.2023 IP:192.168.x.x
kate logon on DESKTOP in 13:42:24,10 23.06.2023 IP:192.168.x.x
```

example logout logs:

```
name logout on NAMEOFPC in time date
kate logout on DESKTOP in 10:05:55,10 23.06.2023
```

I make a table where i can see users who now logon. When they do logout they disappear from the table

Right now I have an idea just to compare the list of usernames from the logout file along with the names from logon. If the one who is in logon is already in logout, he disappears. But our users can log in again, it turns out they will not be displayed, because they will be re-read and compared with past data. I think you can compare in time, but how then. At the output after comparing, I think to get a json dictionary, since then it is convenient to display all the data in the table through js.
If you have any ideas or ways to do this, please help.

Example of code:

```
def logon(logons):  #logons - path to file with logs logon
        logon_result = {}
        
        with open(logons, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            length = len(lines) 
   
                for i in range(length):
                    each_line = lines[i]
                    array_line = each_line.split(' ')
                    length_list = len(array_line)
                    name = array_line[0]
                    logon_result[name] = ('')
                    tmp_list = {}
                    for i in range(length_list):
                        a = array_line[i]
                    
                        if i == 0:
                            name = a
                            tmp_list.setdefault('name', name)
                            
                        if a.isupper():
                            pc = a
                            tmp_list.setdefault('pc', pc)
                                
                        if ':' in a:
                            time = a
                            tmp_list.setdefault('time', time) 
                                        
                        if '.' in a:
                            date = a
                            tmp_list.setdefault('date', date) 

                        logon_result[name] = tmp_list

        return logon_result


    def logout(logouts): #logout - path to file with logs logon
        logout_res = []
        with open(logouts, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            length = len(lines)
            
            for i in range(length):
                each_line = lines[i]
                array_line = each_line.split(' ')
                name = array_line[0]
                logout_res.append(name)  
                
        return logout_res
    
    logon_res = logon(logons)
    logout_res = logout(logouts)  
    
    def result_with_logon_logout(logon_res, logout_res):
        s = set(logout_res)
        res = {k:logon_res[k] for k in logon_res.keys() if k not in s}
        res_dict = dict(sorted(res.items()))
        with open('./dictionary_result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as dictionary:    
            json.dump(res_dict, dictionary) 
       
    result_with_logon_logout(logon_res, logout_res)
```

Comment: How are the files generated? If a standard or at least, processable format is used, loading and comparison will be a *lot* easier. What is the OS? On Windows, login/logout events are always written in the Security Event log which can be read as a database. You can even subscribe forward events to a central server, subscribe to them or actually write them to a database for processing

Comment: Files make with script on powershell in Windows ANSI 
I need take data only from this file

Comment: Windows is Unicode, so what does `Windows ANSI` mean? Made with a script, how? Why not read the real events? The script will run a long time after the real login event, won't record the logout and can be disabled. If you control the script, it's better to use a format that's easy to parse, so you can read the files eg in Pandas and process them

Comment: Check for example [Read Apache logs with Pandas](https://mmas.github.io/read-apache-access-log-pandas). It shows how you can parse a log using regular expressions, load the data into a Dataframe and process them. If you store log events as a *CSV*, you won't even have to parse the file, you can use `pd.read_csv`. After that you can match records by user, login and logout times etc, join different dataframes (login/logout times) or pair consecutive recors, eg the logout with the closest login before it

Comment: In a database you can use windowing functions like `LEAD` and `LAG` to find the previous result in a result set. For example you can get the previous event time for a user with `LAG(LogTime,1) OVER(PARTITION BY User ORDER BY LogTime)`. Pandas can work in a similar way

Comment: I'm sorry The file is created using the cmd .bat script
Encoding - Ansi

Comment: You offer solutions where you need to connect another apache or database, do you think it’s realistic to do this only through python or js, I know js much worse than python, so I plan to only output it from the json dictionary to a web page

Comment: I did nothing of the kind. You talked about a table - that means a database. I linked to an article that shows how to use Python to process log files, similar to what you're asking. And there's no ANSI encoding involved, not that it matters. Even that batch file isn't needed and shouldn't be named `.bat` anyway.

Comment: I suspect you need to rewrite the question to explain what you really want. Are you trying to correlate login/logouts? Generate an HTML report? You can do both with Python eg Pandas has a [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method, to export results to HTML.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do any of that work though? Windows itself has tools to monitor, log and *report* events, remotely, for any number of machines. *And* generate alerts, something no script can dot. There are free tools like [Windows Admin Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/windows-admin-center) that will generate entire dashboards for multiple servers, without even installing any agents or scripts

Comment: I'm making a web page that will have a table of employees who are now online and working at their computer (there are just over 100 of them). I take logs from files, write them to json dictionaries. Log files are created after running the script, which with the .bat extension in cmd. And after that, output by the value of the JSON key to the table row by row through a dynamic table.

Comment: Yes, i need do it

Comment: If you want the currently logged on user you should probably check [Python Find Current User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498307/python-find-current-or-last-logged-on-user). You can ask individual machines for the current user directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initialize an empty dictionary `current_logon_status = {}`, and then process each logon and logout event in the following way:
2. For each logon event, update the `current_logon_status` dictionary with the user's current logon time and computer, overwriting any previous values for that user.
3. For each logout event, check if the user is currently logged on by looking up their name in the `current_logon_status` dictionary. If they are logged on, remove their entry from the dictionary.
4. The `current_logon_status` dictionary will contain the current logon status of each user
5. Convert to JSON object and return it for display.

```
    import json
    
    # Initialize empty dictionary to track current logon status
    current_logon_status = {}
    
    # Process logon events
    with open('logon.txt', 'r') as logon_file:
        for line in logon_file:
            parts = line.strip().split()
            username = parts[0]
            computer = parts[4]
            logon_time = ' '.join(parts[6:8])
            current_logon_status[username] = {'computer': computer, 'logon_time': logon_time}
    
    # Process logout events
    with open('logout.txt', 'r') as logout_file:
        for line in logout_file:
            parts = line.strip().split()
            username = parts[0]
            logout_time = ' '.join(parts[6:8])
            if username in current_logon_status:
                del current_logon_status[username]
    
    # Convert current logon status dictionary to JSON
    current_logon_status_json = json.dumps(current_logon_status)
```

Comment: I didn't incl any code as I don't think it is a good way to learn. 

However I am more than happy to help if you really need any code help.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. An answer should be able to stand by itself. Please check [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @jaspercoleman  will it be correct if there are more than 100 users?
I thought to do it in loops, iterate over the file line by line, and then split the line by space and then iterate over each element with if checks to fit them into the necessary variables. I added code example

Comment: @jaspercoleman That is, it will work like this, the user entered at 7:15 and left at 7:30.
And then the user decided to log in again at 8:00, and then did not log out until the next run of the script
Will it be in the dictionary that he came in at 8:00?

Comment: @Kate 
Do you want to keep track of all log on events? Or only keep track of the latest one?  
Your code block works for the latter (retain latest logon)  
But won't work for keeping the whole list of logon events from the same user.   
Your logon() overwrites the logon information for a user every time it encounters a new logon event for that user

Comment: The code will work no matter the numbers of users.

Comment: I tried to run the code on a real example, and if the user is displayed again in logon.txt, as if he logs in a second time (and before that he logged out, according to the logout.txt logs), then he is also removed from the final result, and he is not in online users, although he has not yet logged out after he logged in a second time. I didn't change the code, do you know how to fix it? This is the hardest problem

Comment: You have to think what you want to do if a user is already logged on like you said from one IP address, and then logs in again from another IP address - is that allowed ? Another question is - if the user logs on from one IP address, and then does not log out but the client device is powered off - and - then tries to login from another device - which may get the same IP address as the first device since this is DHCP - what do you want to do ? @Kate